# Extjs 4 Disable tooltip for PagingToolbar

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have PagingToolbar as bbar of my grid. When tooltip shows up, it renders below my visible screen and that is why vertical scroll shows up, but when it does the vertical scroll takes some place of the viewport so automatically horizontal scroll also shows up overflowing the tooltip. So basically i have 2 questions.

1. The vertical scrolls shows for whole viewport, but grid with bbar is in south region only and grid has already vertical scroll itself. Is there some kind of config to control that behaviour?
2. How to disable tooltips for PagingToolbar i have following code which is not working (grid definition, removed irrelevant) .

```
initComponent: function() {

        var me = this;

        this.store = 'DevPlan';

var paging = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: this.store,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Wyświetlono wnioski {0} - {1} z {2}',
            emptyMsg: "Brak wniosków do wyświetlenia"
        });

        Ext.each(paging.items.items, function(btn) {
            if (btn.getXType() == 'button' && btn.tooltip != undefined) {
                Ext.QuickTips.unregister(btn.getId());
            }
        });

        this.bbar = paging;

this.callParent(arguments);
```

I think maybe the above code is not working because tooltips were not registered yet or bacause the paging toolbar has not been rendered so i tried:

```
afterRender:function() {

        this.callParent();

        var items = this.bbar.items.items;
        Ext.each(items, function(btn) {
            if (btn.getXType() == 'button' && btn.tooltip != undefined) {
                console.log(btn.getId());
                Ext.QuickTips.unregister(btn.getId());
            }
        });
    }
```

but in this code i get this.bbar is undefined. Why? So when is bbar rendered?

Comment: try setting `autoscroll:false` in your viewport

Comment: i need autoScroll to true, there are many paths to work with app and sometimes autoScroll is necessary

Comment: set autoscroll to region's container i.e Panel, instead of viewport

Comment: Still the same, as if tooltip does not belong to container but to whole page body

Comment: Can you try moving the `each` section after the call to `callParent` in your `initComponent()` method.

Comment: Also, do both `initComponent()` and `afterRender()` methods of your grid? What triggers `afterRender()`?

Comment: Moving each after callParent does not help. I dont get Your second question, afterRender i just subclass override of grid afterRender and it is triggered when component is rendered, so it should have bbar defined (i think :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ExtJS4 the bbar is just a short way to apply a toolbar/items as bottom docked and get unsetted after init, see

```
if (me.bbar) {
    docked.push(initToolbar(me.bbar, 'bottom'));
    me.bbar = null;
}
```

I guess you can do it this way (I expected this to be a event, so the comments are):

```
afterrender: function(grid) { 
    // 'this' should not be accessible within a eventcallback! If it is you are within the class definition and should use this.on('beforerender', ...) after the callParent() instead!!
    // callParent() should be called within the init of the class, not somewhere else!
    // this.callParent(); 

    var pagebar = grid.down('pagingtoolbar'),
        items = pagebar ? pagebar.items.items : [],
        len = items.length,
        i = 0;
    // don't use each if it is not really necessary!
    for(;i < len; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item.getXType() === 'button' && item.tooltip != undefined) {
            console.log(item.getId());
            Ext.QuickTips.unregister(item.getId());
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on your last comment: You should not override the afterRender method of the Grid, register yourself to the aftererender event instead and do this within the initComponent() right after the call parent, as written in the comment of the code expample

**Edit 2:**

There is a private method on each button that clears the tooltip. As you might know private methods can still be called like any others but the can completly change/get removed in upcoming framework versions. Most of them can also not be found in the API. The mothod you are looking for is `clearTip()`

Call it on each button instance from which you want to remove the tooltip. That should work.

I totally have overseen your first question: You should consider to remove the scroll behavior from the viewport by using `autoScroll: false` or disabled it from the grid by using `viewConfig: { autoScroll: false, scroll: false }`

Comment: Thanks sra, i get it why bbar is null, but why cant i unregister tooltips in afterRender override? I tested my code with `this.down('pagingtoolbar')` and `console.log(item.getId())` is now returning all the ids. Still unregister(btnid) is not working

Comment: And this.callParent(); in afterRender override just calls the parent's afterRender function, does it not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
{
dock : 'bottom',
xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',
store : store,
pageSize : 25,
displayInfo : true,
firstText:null,
prevText:null,
nextText:null,
lastText:null,
refreshText:null,
....
```